# Vue if statement while display data from api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am getting some data from an Api and I want to check if the vtype is "car". Here is how I loop :

```
<tr v-for="vehicles_group in vehicles_groups.data" :key="vehicles_group.gid">
      <td>
           <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <!-- <td>{{ vehicles_groups.gid }} </td> -->
      <td>{{ vehicles_group.title }}</td>
      <td>{{ vehicles_group.vtype }}</td>
      <td>{{ vehicles_group.company }}</td>
      <td>{{ vehicles_group.active }}</td>
      <td>{{ vehicles_group.priceincludes }}</td>
      <td>{{ vehicles_group.categories }}</td>
      <td>{{ vehicles_group.earlybook }}</td>
      <td>{{ vehicles_group.earlybook }}</td>
 </tr>
```

Is there a way in vue to check if the value of a Api output is car console something?

For example

```
if {{ vehicles_group.vtype }} == car{
   console.log('its a car', vehicles_group.vtype )
}
```

Comment: Your table already tells you whether its a car or not here: <td>{{ vehicles_group.vtype }}</td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.

If you want to use [`v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Conditionals-and-Loops) in your template:

```
<td v-if="vehicles_group.vtype == 'car'">
    It's a car
</td>
<td v-else>
    It's not a car
</td>
```

If you want to this in your component JavaScript code, you can do it as usual:

```js
if (vehicles_group.vtype == "car") {
   console.log('its a car', vehicles_group.vtype )
}
```